# Entity Framework Database First Configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-5

I have the following tables in my database

Notes Table:

- NoteID
- Description
- TaskID (Can be NULL)

Task Table:

- TaskID
- TaskType
- TaskDescription

I an using Entity Framework 5.0 Database First approach.

In some cases there will be notes which linked to a single task but there will be cases that note are standalone that means that they not linked to single task.

My question is how do i need to configure the edmx (model) file so when i am asking for a single task he will give me the associated noted?

I think it something that i need to configure  the mapping no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to configure anything.  Just gen the model from the db and then

```
 var query = context.Tasks.Include("Notes");
```

Comment: I use it when I am creating new query? For example GetAllTasks()?

Comment: Yes,  get all tasks and any notes associated

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing code first then this will do it automatically.  Simply make the TaskId nullable:

```
public class Note
{
    public int NoteID {get; set;}
    public string Description {get; set;}
    public int? TaskId {get; set;} // Notice the int is nullable

    public virtual Task {get; set;}
}

public class Task
{
    public int TaskID {get; set;}
    public TaskTypeEnum TaskType {get; set;}
    public string Description {get; set;}

    public virtual ICollection<Note> Notes {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Doesn't the Task class needs to have List of Notes?